# Xamarin.Forms - make background image visible through toolbar

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I want every page in my app to have a transparent toolbar at the top, and a background image that covers the entire page.

In the App.xaml.cs I have written the following:

```
MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MDMaster())
{
     BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
     BackgroundImage = "background_1.png"
};
```

This will correctly make the toolbar transparent, however the background image is not shown. It's possible for me to add a background color but not a background image.

MDMaster is the master component of a MasterDetailPage. On the MDMaster page I set the Detail page like so:

```
Detail = new NavigationPage(new ProfilePage())
{
    BarBackgroundColor = Color.Transparent,
    BackgroundImage = "background_1.png"
};
```

This does not even show the background image either.

On the ProfilePage, I can write:

```
public ProfilePage()
{
    InitializeComponent();        
    this.BackgroundImage = "background_1.png";
}
```

This will show the background image, however it will not cover the area behind the toolbar even though it's transparent. It ends up looking like this:

[image: Background not showing behind toolbar]

Comment: 1. It is not recommended to add MD page to Navigation page.2. "MDMaster is the master component of a MasterDetailPage". It should be MD page itself, not master component.

Comment: So only the detail page should be a navigation page, not the master page?

Comment: you are correct

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, as @Yuri S suggested, you don't need to wrap your `MasterDetailPage` with `NavigationPage`. Just set the `MasterDetailPage` as the `MainPage` is OK.

Then when you are setting the background image to the root `MasterDetailPage`, the reason why the background image is not showing is because the top NavigationPage is not transparent and it's hiding the background image.

So to fix the problem, you need to set the `BackgroundColor` of `NavigationPage to transparent` too:

```
public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    MainPage = new MasterDetailPage()
    {
        Master=new MainPage(),
        Detail=new NavigationPage(new Detail())
        {
            BarBackgroundColor=Color.Transparent,
            BackgroundColor=Color.Transparent
        },
        BackgroundImage="tianyuan.jpg"
    };
}
```

Then it will show like this:

[image]

If you don't want your status bar to show like above, you can set it manually in Droid project:

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        LoadApplication(new App());

        //set the status bar color
        Window.SetStatusBarColor(Android.Graphics.Color.Black);
    }
}
```

And it will show like this:

[image]

Comment: Ah okay, that shows the background correctly. I have a question though, I have several Navigation.PushAsync(new Page()) in the MasterPage. They don't work anymore since the master page is not a navigation page anymore. What should I do to get that working? I'd like the back button on every page but the MainPage (the MasterDetailPage)

Comment: `MasterPage` is the page used for navigation. Why would you want to change that? I think you should reconsider your project's design. And also, if you have other requirements,please open a new question so that everyone can find that through google.

Comment: I don't want to change it, but how do I navigate from the MasterPage if it's not a navigation page?

Comment: Place a item list in your master page, when clicking the item, change your detail page. The detail page is supposed to change in response to user action on master page.